# Remove highlighted columns and data from jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Is there a way I can delete the highlighted selected columns in this jtable using the remove button? I know there's a way for rows but I'm not sure how to do this for selected columns.

```
private void RemoveColBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  // Removes the highlighted column 
}

private void AddBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  //Add Data
  lMessage.setText("");
  DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) JtableData.getModel();
  if (!ProdNameTF.getText().trim().equals("")) {
    model.addRow(new Object[] {
      ProdNameTF.getText(), CategoryCB.getSelectedItem().toString(), PriceTF.getText()
    });
  } else {
    lMessage.setText("Message Left Blank");
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove columns from the JTable view. The data will still be contained in the TableModel, it just won't be displayed in the JTable.

So the basic code would be:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
tcm.removeColumn( tcm.getColumn(...) );
```

For a more complex solution that allows the user to hide/show columns as they wish check out the [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/).